# Generating a tone using pure javascript with Chromium WebAudio API

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, chromium, web-audio-api

How can I generate a tone (pure sine wave, for instance) using only javascript and Chromium's WebAudio API?

I would like to accomplish something like [the Firefox equivalent](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API#Complete_Example%3a_Creating_a_Web_Based_Tone_Generator).

The Chromium WebAudio demos [here](http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/index.html) appear to all use prerecorded `<audio>` elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not these best way, but I used dsp.js to generate different types of sinusoids, then passed them off to the Web Audio API in this demo: http://www.htmlfivewow.com/demos/waveform-generator/index.html

Comment: Ah yeah, forgot to put down; I basically did the same thing. As of when I asked this question, that demo was more-or-less completely broken. Some friends and I hacked together this http://pastebin.com/7jEqJSCU for a hackathon. It uses DSP to generate sine waves. It also demos an async-loading drum kit. I have no idea if it still works though; it ran in Canary when we built it, but it wouldn't surprise me if tweaking would be necessary now.

Answer (score 23):

The Web Audio API has what's known as the Oscillator Interface to generate the tones you're talking about. They're pretty straight forward to get going...

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext(),
    //Call function on context
    oscillator = context.createOscillator(); // Oscillator defaults to sine wave

oscillator.connect(context.destination);
oscillator.start();
```

You can change the type of wave by doing:

```
oscillator.type = 1; // Change to square wave.
```

or alternatively:

```
oscillator.type = oscillator.SQUARE;
```

I've written [an article about this very topic](http://stuartmemo.com/making-sine-square-sawtooth-and-triangle-waves/) in more detail, so that might be of some use to you!

Comment: Is there no better way of changing the oscillator type than by using a number? it doesn't make for very readable code.

Comment: @frankster Yeah, you can do oscillator.type = oscillator.SQUARE; I'll update the answer.

Comment: Use oscillator.start() instead of oscillator.noteOn(), which no longer exists, see: https://jsfiddle.net/xMruN/322/

Comment: How can I add a time limit?

Comment: @Dewsworld You can do oscillator.start(context.currentTime), then oscillator.stop(context.currentTime + 2) to stop it after 2 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer that does not require an external script. +1